# How to make `<p>` display: inline after linebreak filter?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this in my template:

```
{{ doc.description|linebreaks }}
<a href="#">Edit</a>
```

because the string has linebreaks inside that I want to display. Problem is, I want the Edit button to be displayed inline with the string, and the linebreak filter automatically applies `<p></p>` to the string. How do I make this `<p>` display: inline? (I need to add `class="d-inline"` as I am using bootstrap)

Comment: You can work with `|linebreaksbr` to use `<br>`s over paragraphs (`<p>`).

Comment: That was simple and worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with the [**`|linebreaksbr`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) instead. As the documentation says:

> Converts all newlines in a piece of plain text to **HTML line breaks (`<br>`)**.

So this will not wrap the elements in paragraph tags (`<p>`):

```
{{ doc.description|linebreaksbr }}
<a href="#">Edit</a>
```